# UIViewController to show E-Mails in MIME format?

Tags: ios, email, uiwebview, mime, viewcontroller

I am wondering if there is any open source component to view MIME encoded E-Mail messages? My app does not need to compose messages.

I searched for such a component but cannot find anything related.

I know that there is a MFMailComposeViewController but that looks like it is just for composing new messages.

I also tried the UIWebView if it accepts mime messages - but it does not. :(

I hope someone can help me.

Greetings from Germany